# PHP File Wont Run From Cron

Tags: php, mysql, cron, fopen

I have the following PHP script that establishes a connection to a MySQL database and runs a SQL query to grab 4 fields, then creates a comma separated text file from the output. If I place this PHP file in my public_html folder and browse to it from my web browser, it functions correctly. However I want place this PHP script in a unique folder on the same level as public_html, and call it via a CRON job in my Cpanel. When I do this, I get the attached error.

**script location**
/home2/mywebsite/whereIam/myscript.php

**text file output location**
/home2/mywebsite/public_html/text.txt

**Cron Job**
0   0   *   *   *   /home2/mywebsite/whereIam/myscript.php

**Error Message**

/home2/mysite/whereiam/myscript.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory

/home2/mysite/whereiam/myscript.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home2/mysite/whereiam/myscript.php: line 2:`    $fh = fopen("/home2
/mywebsite/public_html/text.txt", "w");'

```
<?php
    $fh = fopen("/home2/mywebsite/public_html/test.txt", "w");
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user_readoly","SomePassword");
    mysql_select_db("nameofDatabase", $con);

    /* insert field values into data.txt */

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `field_129`, `field_131`,`field_26` FROM  `a_custom_database_5` WHERE `field_129` <> ''");   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {          
        $num = mysql_num_fields($result) ;    
        $last = $num - 1;
        for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {            
            fwrite($fh, $row[$i]);                       
            if ($i != $last) {
                fwrite($fh, ",");
            }
        }                                                                 
        fwrite($fh, "\n");
    }
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: You've forgottent to include the PHP executable in your CRON job so it's trying to execute the PHP code as a `bash` script. Your cron command should look like this: `php  /home2/mywebsite/whereIam/myscript.php`

Comment: Try adding the command to the cron job like `0 0 * * * php /home2/mywebsite/whereIam/myscript.php`, does that help? Alternatively, you can add `#!/usr/bin/php` as a first line to the script, and set the permissions to executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- Change the cronjob to:

  ```
  0 0 * * * php /home2/mywebsite/whereIam/myscript.php
  ```

  Notice that the `php` command has been added with as argument the filename. Otherwise, cron tries to execute the PHP file, but it doesn't know it should be executed as PHP.
- There's a way to tell the OS the PHP file should be executed as PHP. Add this as a first line to the script:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/php
  ```

  Also set the permissions such that the file is executable. Now, you could execute it from a shell as if it's a command - and also the cronjob works without modification.

  This is of course assuming the PHP executable is in `/usr/bin/php`. You can use the command `which php` to find the location on your system.

Which to choose is a matter of personal preference I suppose. I like the second option because it allows you to execute the file from the command line without explicitly using the `php` command. However, with the second option moving to another server with possibly a different path to `php` means you have to edit the file - which isn't needed with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home2/mywebsite/whereIam/myscript.php`

And I would also redirect the output to a log file so then change it to this

`0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home2/mywebsite/whereIam/myscript.php >> /path/to/log.php 2&>1`

This is assuming that php is at /usr/bin/php